# Diversify "podcasts" to "recordings"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently retagged [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15565/where-can-i-find-transcripts-of-actual-game-sessions) from [system-agnostic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-agnostic) to [podcast](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/podcast) because I was trying to reduce the number of questions that had the [system-agnostic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-agnostic) tag and nothing else and [podcast](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/podcast) was obviously clearly *related* even if it didn't seem *directly* applicable (the question specifies written transcripts rather than audio or AV recordings).

Would it make sense to either create a more general [game-recordings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recordings) tag (or something along those lines) and retag the [podcast](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/podcast) questions, or alternately to simply make a synonym for the [podcast](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/podcast) tag (I'll admit to not knowing much about about how tag synonyms work)?

Comment: There are RPG podcasts that are not game recordings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because it'll never get used and no one will think to use it?

Tagging here should be emergent.  People know "podcast" and will tag using it and search using it, it's obviously useful. Something more general isn't.

For written summaries, common terms are "session summaries," "story hours" and "actual plays".  You can try one of those on for size for that Q I'd think.

Comment: I just don't like having tags that only apply to a single question, as appears to be the case here.

Comment: found another in 10s of looking http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8691/where-to-find-game-session-reports/8707#8707

Comment: "Actual play" is a thing I'd like to see-- at least as a synonym.

Comment: sure, will add a couple

Comment: Added story-hour, campaign-journal, actual-play